# Need to add all receipent into BCC

Tags: excel, vba

I wanted to add all the recipient into BCC only macro is adding only 1st email address into BCC and rest all are in "To"

```
arr = ws.Range("I2:I" & LastRow)

Set Mail_Object = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

first = 2

For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    If i = UBound(arr) Then GoTo YO
    If arr(i + 1, 1) = arr(i, 1) Then
        first = WorksheetFunction.Min(first, i + 1)
    Else
YO:
    Set OutApp = Mail_Object.CreateItem(0)

    With OutApp
        .Subject = "ASI Portfolio Holdings" & Replace(ws.Range("J" & i +      1).Value, "Portfolio Holdings Distribution -", "")
        .Body = "Your message here"
        Atthfile = Pth & _
           "JUN2019_fund_" & _
           Replace(ws.Range("I" & i + 1).Value, "Portfolio Holdings Distribution - Fund ", "") & _
           ".xls"

        '~~> If file is found, attach else continue without attaching
        If Dir(Atthfile) <> "" Then .Attachments.Add Atthfile

        .Display
        .bcc = ws.Range("F" & i + 1).Value
        For j = first To i
            .Recipients.Add ws.Range("F" & j).Value
```

Comment: it's dynamic and get change every time

Comment: Please read what a [mcve] is and provide one. Reading [ask] might help too to improve your question.

Comment: every cell has only one email address in it

Comment: Can I see the complete code which includes the complete loop of `i` and `j`?

Comment: if I change .bcc to .to it is capturing all the email address into "TO" but I wall all email address to be in "bcc"

Comment: complete code added

Comment: Doesn't `.Recipients.Add` add recipients to the `To` field?

Comment: Your code is doing exactly what you are asking it to. Collect all the emails separated by a `;` and store them in a string variable. Once you have all the email in the string variable, assign that to `.BCC`. For example `.BCC = MyVariable` where `MyVariable` holds values like `aaa@aaa.com; bbb@bb.com...`

Comment: it's adding into "TO" field I want it to be into "BCC" field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Siddharth said in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57358096/need-to-add-all-receipent-into-bcc#comment101203426_57358096):

> Your code is doing exactly what you are asking it to.[...]

The [Recipients.Add methd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipients.add) adds recipients to your normal recipient list. for the blind carbon copy list you Need to use the [MailItem.BCC property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.bcc).
If you replace the line `.Recipients.Add ws.Range("F" & j).Value` with `.BCC = .BCC & ";" & ws.Range("F" & j).Value` you should get your expected result.

Or, as Sid also suggested in his comment, you can collect the mailaddresses in your loop and assign the bcc recipients later:

```
Dim bccRecipients as String
For j = first To i
    bccRecipients = bccRecipients & ";" & ws.Range("F" & j).Value
    '[...]
Next
.BCC = bccRecipients
```

Comment: still not picking all the email address from range

Comment: This adds all recipients to the BCC list, which you asked about in your question. Maybe your problem is something entirely different? I'm guessing you're not correctly looping over your range. Look at the value of `i`

Comment: only 1st email recipient is getting add into "BCC" not all in the given range

Comment: There is no given range. You are looping from `first` to `i`, if `first` is greater than `i` there is nothing to loop and thus nothing to add to `.BCC`. Again, check your `i`.

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook Application can be used like this:

```
        Set OutMail = Mail_Object.CreateItem(0)

        With OutMail
            .To = "first.last@company.xyz"
            .CC = "a.b@company.xyz; c.d@company.xyz"
            .BCC = "blind@company.xyz; blind2@company.xyz"
            .Subject = "Subject-Field"
            .Body = "Here you can insert the body of the e-mail."
            'You can add other files also like this
            '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
            .Send
        End With
```

So in your case you wouldn't add them to the recipients, but to the bcc-field like this:

```
Dim bccText As String

For j = first To i
   bccText = bccText & ws.Range("F" & j).Value & "; "
Next

.BCC = bccText
```

instead of:

```
For j = first To i
   .Recipients.Add ws.Range("F" & j).Value
```

Comment: I wanted to add recipient into bcc only but with bcc = ws.Range("F" & i + 1).Value
        For j = first To i
            .Recipients.Add ws.Range("F" & j).Value it is adding all the recipient into "TO"